# Auto converting data from a datetime field to a specific format in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hi is possible **automatically** to format (using date()) all data from a datetime field in CakePHP?
I'm thinking about using a callback function in the model but I don't know if I could filter fields coming from a datetime type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something you just want to apply a single model you could use the [afterFind and beforeSave callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/view/76/Callback-Methods) to reformat the date.

If it's something you want to apply to many models you should create a [Behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/595/Creating-Behaviors) for it. You could use an array that tells it what date fields it should format.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm missing something in your question, but if you can get a date into a common string format, you can format it with PHP's `date` function and the `strToTime` function.

```
$date = 'January 27th, 2008'; //almost any format for dates in common usage
echo date('Y-m-d', strToTime($date));

//will print
2009-01-27
```

Comment: yes sorry it was my fault. what i meant was to automatically format all datetime fields to a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like hacking CakePHP's codebase, why don't you just code a wrapper function for find inside your controller? You will have to stick to a naming convention to easily identify your datetime fields but hey naming conventions are good right?

Something like: http://pastebin.com/mbbe91fe